# Is it possible to use JavaScript in a Facebook fan page iframe tab?

Tags: facebook

I have an application at http://www.facebook.com/LovingPets?fbhref=index.php&app_page=1&v=app_190518734309657&sk=app_190518734309657#!/LovingPets?fbhref=treats.php&app_page=1&v=app_190518734309657&sk=app_190518734309657.

I keep getting problems with trying to run JavaScript. I thought that one of the benefits of Facebook adding the iframe to the page tabs is so that you could run JavaScript? When you try to click on the treat catalog link it loads the next page fine, but none of the interactivity works. Looking at Firebug these errors are observed,

> script is not an allowed DOM element [Break On This Error] (11 out of range 3)"

and

> a190518734309657_l is null [Break On This Error] <script type="text/javascript">

Is it possible to run JavaScript and jQuery the way I have my application setup? And if it is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I have been working with jQuery in the new iframe tabs. However, you must update your page to the new layout in order to get them working correctly.

http://www.webtlk.com/2011/02/11/how-to-upgrade-to-the-new-facebook-fan-page-layout-redesign/

Regards

Comment: i have been banging my head on the wall for days trying to figure this out.  Thank yo, thank you thank you!!!